# Calling local files from C++ executable in PATH

Tags: c++, filesystems

Lets say I have a folder called `/folder` that looks like this:

```
folder
|--test.txt
|--test.cpp
```

All `test.cpp` does is print the contents of the (relatively) local `./test.txt`. So if I compile `test.cpp` to get `test.exe`. Then I can call:

```
C:/.../folder>test
```

and the content of test.txt will be printed to the console.

However, if I add `/folder` to my `PATH` variable, I can call the `test` command from anywhere on my command line. Unfortunately, the program can no longer find the `test.txt` file. How can I fix this without using an absolute path? I'm working on a command line tool to aid in development.

Comment: the PATH is used for finding executable files, not data files - you need to provide the path to the data file either via a command line parameter or a configuration file with a known location.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's a bad idea to assume that "test.txt" lives in the same folder as the executable. It is better to pass it as a command line argument.

```
test.exe "<path to folder>/test.txt"
```

or

```
test "<path to folder>/test.txt"
```

Comment: This is a general observation and not an answer to the question as present. There is nothing wrong in principle to have a text file as a part of the application package and put it side-by-side with the executable. Not a Linux way, but a Windows way for certain.

Comment: @SergeyA, I beg to differ. From the OP: *How can I fix this without using an absolute path?* One solution is to provide that as a command line argument.